# In VIM, how to highlight the user defined data type?

Tags: vim

when I was using C language,it is very common to use typedef.
for example,

```
typedef struct man{
    char *head;
    char *body;
    ...
}MAN_t,*MAN_p_t;
```

I really want the `MAN_t` and `MAN_p_t` here to be highlighted in vim as a new data type.

How to make this?

I cannot find a feasible solution online. 
Someone uses `match Type /\w*_t/` but this will make any variable ended with `_t` highlighted.

I wonder is there a way to let vim detect the word after `typedef struct ...{...}`.
What is the regex of it?

Answer (score 1):

I have `*_f` and `*_t` highlighted as `cType`.

Just add this to .vim/syntax/c.vim

```
syn match cType "\<[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*_[ft]\>"
```

If you just want `*_t`

```
syn match cType "\<[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*_[t]\>"
```

Comment: You can find my `vim` config files to help in [github](https://github.com/utix/dotfiles/blob/master/vim/syntax/c.vim)

Comment: Thanks a lot, this does help. But do you understand that regex?

Comment: @K.JIN yes I understand it well, \< and \> match at word boundaries, the word should start with a letter and can have letters and numbers and must finish with `_t`

Comment: What does _f mean?

Comment: @dlitz for function for exampl https://github.com/Intersec/lib-common/blob/master/src/asn1/writer.h#L212